# C# using WebClient to download chunked encoded content

Tags: c#, chunked-encoding

I wrote a client application that is suppose to download a file from a web server, very simple:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile("http://localhost/audiotest/audio.wav", 
                           @"C:\audio.wav");
}
```

The web site (where audio file located: http://localhost/audiotest/audio.wav) has header Transfer-Encoding: chunked

When I run the program, I get following error:

> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseBody
>   Detail=Response chunk format is invalid

How can I download the file when server contains Transfer-Encoding: chunked header?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried it but this might work:

If you forcefully send an request for Http 1.0 rather than Http 1.1 then server will reply with
 HTTP Header specifying Content-Length

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/audiotest/audio.wav");
wr.ProtocolVersion = Version.Parse("1.0"); 

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

You will get the file as stream in `response.GetResponseStream()`

All credit to author of [this](http://blog.degree.no/2011/06/webclient-httpwebresponse-problems-with-chunked-transfer-encoding/)